# My HtmlHelper is losing Html Encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am trying to use a custom HtmlHelper in my view to display a link, but it's getting HTML Encoded.

In my view, I'm calling my helper like this:

```
<td>
    @Html.Urls(item.TaskUrl)
</td>
```

And my helper looks like this:

```
public static class MkpHelpers
{
    public static string Urls(this HtmlHelper helper, string value)
    {
        var items = value.Split(';'); // use your delimiter
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var i in items)
        {
            var linkBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
            linkBuilder.MergeAttribute("href",i);
            linkBuilder.InnerHtml = i;
            sb.Append(linkBuilder.ToString());
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Rendered out, it looks like this:

```
&lt;a href="http://localhost:63595/project/reviewresource/99ddb0d8-238a-e511-8172-00215e466552"&gt;
    http://localhost:63595/project/reviewresource/99ddb0d8-238a-e511-8172-00215e466552
&lt;/a&gt;
```

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong that should be pretty simple/obvious.

Comment: Have you tried `@Html.Raw()` in your view?

Answer (score 3):

Be careful here of Injection attacks.  That being said, you need to return an HtmlString:

```
public static class MkpHelpers
{
  public static HtmlString Urls(this HtmlHelper helper, string value)
  {
    var items = value.Split(';'); // use your delimiter
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var i in items)
    {
        var linkBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
        linkBuilder.MergeAttribute("href",i);
        linkBuilder.InnerHtml = i;
        sb.Append(linkBuilder.ToString());
    }
    return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
  }
}
```

[HtmlString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx) derrives from [IHtmlString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring(v=vs.118).aspx):

> Represents an HTML-encoded string that should not be encoded again.